# Meaning of the parameters in the function detail::GraphCutSeamFinder in opencv

Tags: opencv, opencv-stitching

Now, I have a stitching project. I need to find the best stitching seam, but I have no idea of the function below. I have already seen the illustration of OpenCV documentation, I think it’s unclear.

```
seam_finder = new detail::GraphCutSeamFinder(GraphCutSeamFinderBase::COST_COLOR);
seam_finder->find(images_warped_f, corners, masks_warped);
```

Can someone help me? tell me the meaning of `images_warped_f` and `corners`.Thank u so much!

Answer (score 0):

For every image we have type defined. You can check [here](http://ninghang.blogspot.in/2012/11/list-of-mat-type-in-opencv.html) for more information. images_warped_f is the vector of images converted to type 5.
Corners is the vector of left corner points of the images you are trying to stitch. If you use the SphericalWarper to warp your image, the warp function would perform a spherical projectiona and return you the top left corner of the result image. You can check [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d6/dd0/classcv_1_1detail_1_1SphericalWarper.html) for reference.

Comment: Could you provide an example for it?